# The first micromouse competition in 1977 had 6000 initial entries, what would the majority of them have been (e.g. wall followers)?

Tags: history, robotics

The [first micromouse competition in 1977](https://micromouseonline.com/micromouse-book/history/), had 6000 initial entries, what would the majority of them have been (e.g. wall followers)?

- **Note** - In the link above, [first micromouse competition in 1977](https://micromouseonline.com/micromouse-book/history/), it states that the competition was announced in 1977, to be held in 1979, and there were 6000 initial entries. So there would not have been a micromouse competition in 1977.  So an uncertainty would be, was the first micromouse competition held in 1978, or, 1979, since a comment below has a link citing 1978 as the first micromouse competition .
- 6000 initial entries is way more than I would have thought, however then I thought that maybe every decent sized town may have had a little robotics club, and in those days robotics clubs may have been more common than computer clubs.
- Another possibility could be that a large number of those entries were not from robotics clubs, but rather, just people after the prize money or something, so they just maybe adapted something like cheap electric toy cars to be wall followers.

Comment: Mostly wall-followers I'd assume.  You'll note that the maze designs were changed in later years to render wall following ineffective.  For context, a wall-following robot can be as simple as two wheels, a chassis, a battery, two motors, and a feeler-actuated switch turning one motor on or off.

Comment: Also note it's **extremly easy** to make a wall follower robot. You only need two sensors, two motors, and a bit of discrete electronics. No search tree, no memory. It was a big fashion to build those at this time (as I said in the other answer, I build one, too, with help from my father, using Fischer-Technik, and I never was in a robotics club).

Comment: I imagined that the simplest design would be,  something even simpler,  a 2-wheeled motor-cycle shaped vehicle,  that leans ( weighted ) extremely to one side, and on that side of the motorcyle are 1, or 2,  balls or wheels,  which are turned by an electric motor,  they would have traction against the wall,  the ground wheels of the motorcycle would be un-powered,  is there any reason that would not have solved the 1977 micromouse maze ?

Comment: Or a variation of the simplest design I just posted, to allow it to do a 180-degree turn around the edge of a single wall of the maze ?

Comment: Also, if this motor-cycle shaped design I posted in the above comments, tended to keep slipping down and away from the wall, an unpowered side wheel on an arm could force the vehicle to steer closer to the wall whenever it touches against the ground

Comment: http://davidbuckley.net/RS/mmouse/micromouse78.htm contains some information about the contest (announced 1977, held 1979). There are also links to other sites.

Comment: As I understand the things I read so far about the competition, there were 6000 teams paying the registration fee. Having a working robot (or even having any idea how to make that robot) was apparently not necessary at this step.  It seems that at least some of the top 10 robots were not from some random computer or robot club, but from companies.

Comment: I was about to type  -  "Your comments, and link, giving the explanation that most of the initial 6000 entries, were just people from around the world paying the entry fee, seems to be the best available answer". However,  I notice your link is for 1978.  The link that I give in the question, states that the competition was announced in 1977, to be held in 1979, and there were 6000 initial entries.  There may be some discrepancy regarding the years, between  the link I give in the question, and your link, either way, your explanation of the 600 initial entries seems the best available.

Comment: I just want to mention another, even simpler wall follower I was thinking of, a cheap electric toy car, with steering that can be moved. So, the steering would be set to be permanently pointing slightly to the left, or, to the right.  Then, remove the bottom chassis from one or two small diecast toy cars, and stick it to the sides of the car, so that the car will not scrape against the wall. And, most importantly, connect an unpowered wheel to the front of the car ( probably on the end of an arm, set at an appropriate angle ), so the car will turn at square corners, instead of getting stuck